# Markers on Horizontal Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to align tick marks on a horizontal slider that steps by 5 units. I have two issues:

```
1 - How do I make the slider longer to accommodate the tick marks?
2 - How do I properly align these tick marks directly under the slider, each representing each 5units point on the slider?
```

Right now, I used a table for the markers because I felt that would push the start marker to the beginning of the slider line - not getting desired output.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!-- Slider.html-->


<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slider.css">

<head>
    <title>Slider</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="action_page.php" method="get">
        Steps:
        <input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="40" step="5">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <table>
          <td>
            <table>

                <td>
                  <div class="checkpoint">
                    <div class="tick"></div>
                    <div class="value">5</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="checkpoint">
                    <div class="tick"></div>
                    <div class="value">10</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="checkpoint">
                    <div class="tick"></div>
                    <div class="value">15</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="checkpoint">
                    <div class="tick"></div>
                    <div class="value">20</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="checkpoint">
                    <div class="tick"></div>
                    <div class="value">25</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="checkpoint">
                    <div class="tick"></div>
                    <div class="value">30</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="checkpoint">
                    <div class="tick"></div>
                    <div class="value">35</div>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div class="checkpoint">
                    <div class="tick"></div>
                    <div class="value">40</div>
            </td>

    </table>

  </td>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my .css:

```
/*slider.css*/
.checkpoint {
  text-align: center;
  float: center;
}
.tick {
  border-left: 1px solid #454545;
  width: 41px;
  height: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.value {
    border-left: 1px;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 41px;
    height: 5px;
    display: below-block;
}
.checkpoint:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.style {
    left: 56.5px;
    position: relative;
}
```

My output gives me this:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you could do is use the css property `width` to change the length of the slider at which point you could then use the margin on the table in order to align the two. if you don't want to have to do a lot of guessing you could use jquery to get those lengths using jquery. to make it easier ive edited your tic marks to be a horizontal line and added some other css to appropriately compensate

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.slider').css('width',$('table').css('width'));
 $('.measure').css('margin-left',$('.steps').css('width'));
 });
```

```css
.checkpoint {
   text-align: center;
   float: center;
 }
 .tick {
 text-align:right;
   border:none;
   width: 41px;
   height: 5px;
   display: inline-block;
 }
 .value {
 text-align:center;
  border-left: 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 41px;
  height: 5px;
  display: below-block;
 }
 .checkpoint:not(:last-child) {
   margin-right: 20px;
 }

 .style {
  left: 56.5px;
  position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

 <head>
  <title>Slider</title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <form action="action_page.php" method="get">
   <span class='steps'>Steps:</span>
   <input class='slider' type="range" name="points" min="0" max="40" step="5">
   <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <table class='measure'>
     <td>
    <table>

     <td>
       <div class="checkpoint">
      <div class="tick">|</div>
      <div class="value">5</div>
     </td>
     <td>
      <div class="checkpoint">
      <div class="tick">|</div>
      <div class="value">10</div>
     </td>
     <td>
      <div class="checkpoint">
      <div class="tick">|</div>
      <div class="value">15</div>
     </td>
     <td>
      <div class="checkpoint">
      <div class="tick">|</div>
      <div class="value">20</div>
     </td>
     <td>
      <div class="checkpoint">
      <div class="tick">|</div>
      <div class="value">25</div>
     </td>
     <td>
      <div class="checkpoint">
      <div class="tick">|</div>
      <div class="value">30</div>
     </td>
     <td>
      <div class="checkpoint">
      <div class="tick">|</div>
      <div class="value">35</div>
     </td>

     <td>
      <div class="checkpoint">
      <div class="tick">|</div>
      <div class="value">40</div>
    </td>

  </table>

   </td>

  </table>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: which document does the "$(document).ready(function(){ ... }" script go to? i have just the .html and .css files. I'm not sure where to insert that. //sorry, new to this

Comment: It makes sure the document is loaded before jquery starts messing with it you would put it in a JavaScript file which is .js and it loads through a script tag

Comment: Script tags look like this <script src='script.js'></script>

Comment: You'll also need to load jquery which you can either download or use a public distribution like the ones hosted on the Google developers page. that's just if you want to use jquery

Comment: You could also do script in your html within your opening and closing script tags

Comment: this looks good, but how do i move the tick marker to align with the values at their proper steps?

Comment: You mean you want the tick marks on the other side of the numbers? Change the text alignment for the tick marks to right